# How to pass values to a function which is a list item in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, function

I want to pass a value as argument in a function which is a list item.

For example:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    print(“Something is happening here”, arg1, arg2 )


l = [1,2,3, foo('want values here as arguments')] 

def foo_bar():
    x = 0, y = 1
    print(“want to pass x and y inside: “ , l[3])
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

```py
 def foo(arg1, arg2):
    print("Something is happening here", arg1, arg2 )


l = [1,2,3, foo] 

def foo_bar():
    x = 0
    y = 1
    print("want to pass x and y inside: " , l[3](x,y))
```

Answer (score 1):

You write

```
l = [1,2,3,foo]
```

and later

```
print l[3](x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to store the result from `foo()` in your list, you need to reorder the steps in your code. I recommend storing the return result from `foo()` as a variable:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    print(“Something is happening here”, arg1, arg2 )



def foo_bar():
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = foo(x, y)
    l = [1,2,3, z] 
    print(l)
```

Alternatively, you can create the list and then append values to it:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    print(“Something is happening here”, arg1, arg2 )


l = [1,2,3] 


def foo_bar():
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = foo(x, y)
    l.append(z)
    print(l)
```